# How to write greek latters in encoding iso_8859_1?

Tags: gnuplot

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set xlabel "{/:Italic {/Symbol l}} ({\305})" font "Latin Modern Roman,12" enhanced
```

How to write lambda with this code? Thank you

Comment: How are you displaying it. Eg. if you're using x11 as your terminal. `set term x11 enhanced` would show symbols.

Comment: Works fine on `wxt` terminal.